# function to return comma separated list of meta values

Tags: functions, admin, actions

I'm customizing the admin edit.php screen and I have a column that displays a meta key `$gear`. But it only lists the first value instead of returning a list of all the values. Here's the bit that matters:

```
add_action( 'manage_artists_posts_custom_column', 'manage_artists_columns', 10, 2 );
function manage_artists_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    switch( $column ) {
        case 'gear' :
        $gear = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gear', true ); 
            if ( empty( $gear ) )
                echo __( '' );
            else
                printf( __( '%s' ), $gear );

            break;

        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

I use a similar `get_post_meta()` call on the front end that uses

```
if( $gear = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gear') 
echo implode( $gear, ', ' );
```

but I couldn't get it to adapt to this application. How do i get printf to output all values?

Comment: Why are you using `__()` inside a `printf()` call here? There's nothing to be translated. Also, what do you get with `var_dump( $gear )`?

Comment: Short answer? I have no idea. I've cobbled together pieces of code from the interwebs to achieve something way outside of my skill set. All I know is that it works... well, this one problem aside. by `var_dump( $gear )` are you referring to the single post code? $gear is a custom field I've set up so the gear each artist uses can be attached to their profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$gear = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gear', true );
```

… will return the last value only, because you told it do that with the last parameter. Drop it, and you will get an array of all values:

```
$gear = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gear' );
```

Then print it with:

```
print join( $gear, ', ' );
```

And as Chip has pointed out: Do not use the translation function for values that are not translatable. And even translatable values need a text domain.

Comment: JOIN!! Thank you so much. I tried so many variations of print, echo, implode, etc, just throwing spagetti at the wall. `join` is new to me and that did the trick. Only for anyone else this will help, the "true" needs to be removed :) (I assume that was a typo).

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. :) `join()` is an alias of `implode()`.

Comment: I'm learning :) That's the main reason I am doing this by hand instead of searching for a plethora of plug-ins. Thanks again!